# Show $f(x)=2x$ is measurable.

Tags: measure-theory

I am not sure if I understand it. Is that correct?

> Show that $f(x)=2x$ is measurable.

$1) \quad\alpha < 0$

$\{x: f(x) < \alpha \}=(-\infty,\frac{\alpha}{2})$

$2) \quad \alpha=0$

$\{x:f(x)<0\} = (-\infty, 0)$

$3)\quad \alpha >0  $

$\{x: f(x) < \alpha \}=(-\infty,\frac{\alpha}{2})$

These sets are measurable so function is measurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct, using the theorem stating that if $f^{-1}(B)$ is measurable for all $B$ in some generator of the $\sigma$-algebra being used, then $f$ is measurable. Since $\{ (-\infty,a) \mid a\in \mathbb R\}$ is a generator for the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R$, $f$ is measurable with respect to this $\sigma$-algebra. Note too that you didn't need to make a distinction between $\alpha < 0$, $\alpha = 0$ and $\alpha > 0$ since in all cases, $f^{-1}((-\infty,a)) = (-\infty, a/2)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that continuous functions are always measurable. A short and simple answer can be found here: [f a real, continuous function, is it measurable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696124/f-a-real-continuous-function-is-it-measurable)