# If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, are $X^2$ and $Y^2$ also independent?

Tags: statistics

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, are $X^2$ and $Y^2$ also independent?

Can this be proven?

Comment: What do you think the difference between the 2 comparisons is?

Comment: Does squaring add some kind of correlation?

Comment: Can you show your attempts for to solve this problem?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/8742/321264

Answer (score 3):

To prove that 2 (discrete) random variables are independent, it boils down to showing that $P(A=a, B=b) = P(A=a)P(B=b)$ all the time.
If they are not independent, then we must find a counter example.

If we suspect that they are independent, then we want to show that:

> (Case when $x\neq 0, y \neq 0$)
> P( X = x^2, Y = y^2 ) = P( X = x OR X = -x, Y = y OR Y = -y)
> = P( X = x, Y = y) +  P( X = -x, Y = y ) + ...
> = ?
> = ? P(X = x^2 ) P(Y= y^2)

Can you take it from here?
Must this equality be true? How are we using the independence of $X, Y$?
What about the case when $ x =0$?
What if the random variables are continuous, or a mix?

---

More generally, we say that if $X, Y$ are independent, then for measurable functions $f, g$, we get that $f(X), g(Y)$ is also independent.
The proof is immediate from understanding measurable functions.

If you haven't learn about measurable functions, then just think of them "reasonable, nicely behaving functions" like $ f(x) = x^2$. The proof follows by a similar approach as above.

Comment: It would be more helpful in general to replace $A=a$ with $A\in S$ etc.

Comment: @J.G. Agreed. I was making an assumption about how familiar OP was with the setup, based on their comment on "adding correlation". What I've described is a start to understanding the question, and there are still some missing details (as hinted by the questions at the end) which vary depending on the depth of understanding.

Answer (score 2):

The technical way to prove this...

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, and suppose $X, Y: (\Omega, \mathcal{F}) \to (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, where $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the collection of Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}$, and $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ denotes the measurable space consisting of the sample space $\Omega$ with a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\Omega$ given by $\mathcal{F}$.

Let $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $g(x) = x^2$. [Because $g$ is continuous over $\mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696124/f-a-real-continuous-function-is-it-measurable), we have that $g: (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})) \to (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$.

Thus, for any $A, B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, $g^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and $g^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. By definition of $X$ and $Y$ being independent, it follows that $X^{-1}(g^{-1}(A))$ and $Y^{-1}(g^{-1}(B))$ are independent. Thus, $(g \circ X)^{-1}(A)$ and $(g \circ Y)^{-1}(B)$ are independent for any $A, B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

It follows that $g(X) = X^2$ and $g(Y) = Y^2$ are independent random variables.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, we have: For any Borel functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ , if $X,Y$ are independent, then $f(X),g(Y)$ are
also independent.

The proof is just few lines: Observe that $\sigma(f(X)):=\{f(X)^{-1}(B)\mid B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}=\{X^{-1}(f^{-1}(B))\mid B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}\subseteq\sigma(X)$.
Similary $\sigma(g(Y))\subseteq\sigma(Y)$. It is given that for any
$A\in\sigma(X)$ and $B\in\sigma(Y)$, $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$. Therefore,
it is trivial that for any $A\in\sigma(f(X))$ and $B\in\sigma(f(Y))$,
$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$.